# Multiple projects in trac

Tags: svn, project-management, trac

How can I manage multiple SVN repositories/trac instances easily? I have a bunch of projects that I want to consolidate into a single authentication scheme. Also, I want to be able to enable plugins for every project and configure a bunch of trac options for multiple projects all at one time.

It would also be nice to be able to add and remove projects from a web interface.

Thanks

-Nelson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We hit the same problem with trac, our solution was to move to [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

Comment: that looks very interesting indeed. wasn't aware of this. at first sight, looks like a trac-clone plus the features I'd been missing in trac...

Comment: no, trac plugins don't work there, it's a completely separate system. It does have some form of modules system. I'm not saying it's a universal - just that switching to trac was the right solution for us.

Comment: Oh man. Oh man. Really. Redmine is the best. Thanks alot. This software ROCKS. Also, be sure to get the mylyn connector with it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/redmin-mylyncon/ :D

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you were looking for.

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the trac-part of your question you might want to keep an eye on this question:
[How do you handle multiple (overlapping) projects in trac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268039/how-do-you-handle-multiple-overlapping-projects-in-trac)

Answer (score 3):

Some answers here are quite outdated, because meanwhile Trac and especially its plugins have made much progress. IMO it's not necessary anymore to change to Redmine. Here's the current state of the art, especially what is maintained and useful:

Look also at the [plugin recommendation site of Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PluginList). IMO best is when you add the following plugins to a freshly installed Trac-1.0:

- SimpleMultiProjectPlugin (multiple projects in one Trac instance)
- AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin (own ticket states and work flow transitions like 'testing')
- TimingAndEstimationPlugin (worked hours, planned hours)
- EstimationToolsPlugin (burndown and workload chart)
- TracJsGanttPlugin (Gantt chart)
- MasterTicketsPlugin (ticket dependency)
- ​SubticketsPlugin (ticket hierarchy)
- ChildTicketsPlugin (parent child relationship)
- FullBlogPlugin (blog & news)
- TracTicketStatsPlugin (work flow statistics)
- AutocompleteUsersPlugin (user name autocompletion)
- UserManagerPlugin (users and roles)
- UpcomingMilestonesChartMacro (milestone date chart)

This is a good combination of all you need for good project-management. They can all be found at trac-hacks.org and plugin installation is quite easy for Trac.

The support of multiple repositories is a build-in feature of Trac itself since 0.12.

Also take a look at the upcoming [Apache Bloodhound project](http://bloodhound.apache.org/) which is build on top of Trac and is also an alternative to what I've written above.

Answer (score 1):

Nelson --

I believe the functionality you are looking for does not exist in standard Trac distributions.

Not sure if you are able to use a Subversion hosting / Trac hosting service, but there are several services that will give you all of this, plus zero setup/maintenance headaches.  Some of these have free or low-cost options that might fit your needs.

http://www.projecthut.com

http://www.projectlocker.com/

http://sourcerepo.com

http://wush.net

There are lots more, which a Google search for "Subversion hosting" or "Trac hosting" would turn up.

Full disclosure: I work for ProjectLocker.

Comment: I need to be able to host it myself. But thanks for the links! I'll keep them in mind :)